# SessionAttributes not working with spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-session

I have face problem to keep email a live data cross pages via session I have try this

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/sec")
@SessionAttributes("reset_user_email")
public class SecurityController {}
```

1. Receive variable  from "/sec/forget"

   ```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/forget/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public ModelAndView forget_page_d(@ModelAttribute User user, ModelAndView mv) 
       throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException, NoSuchPaddingException, UnsupportedEncodingException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException
   {
   mv.addObject("user", user);

   mv.addObject("reset_user_email", user.getEmail());

   //etc
   }
   ```
2. Using `reset_user_email` in "/sec/forget/user/a"

   ```
   @RequestMapping(value = "/forget/user/a", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public ModelAndView forget_page_p(@ModelAttribute String reset_user_email) {
        ModelAndView mv =new ModelAndView();

       mv.setViewName("security/forget_renew");
       mv.addObject("user",reset_user_email);
       System.out.println("a GET user mail = " +reset_user_email);
   ```

Console Output :

```
a GET user mail =
```

what is messing to keep my reset_user_email available everywhere in application ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can manipulate the session attributes by:

1. including the a HttpSession in the method definition:

   ```
   @RequestMapping("/request")
   public ModelAndView getRequest(@ModelAttribute User user, ModelAndView mv, HttpSession session) {
        mv.addObject("reset_user_email", user.getEmail());

        session.setAttribute("reset_user_email", user.getEmail());
        String resetUserEmail = session.getAttribute("reset_user_email");         
   }
   ```
2. Use WebUtils class:

   ```
   @RequestMapping("/request")
   public ModelAndView getRequest(@ModelAttribute User user, ModelAndView mv, HttpServletRequest request) {
        mv.addObject("reset_user_email", user.getEmail());

        WebUtils.setSessionAttribute(request, "reset_user_email", user.getEmail());
        String resetUserEmail = WebUtils.getSessionAttribute(request, "reset_user_email");  
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ModelAndView, Try java.util.Map, try to put session values in Map, by `map.put("your session name",value);`

and try to get a value by `String email=(String)map.get("your session name");`